# Microsoft IIS Virtual Directory: Host images on local server, show on local website

Tags: web, iis

I am developing a website, and publishing / seeing results on my machine. I want to store images on a LAN server, that others may access on their local machine for website development. Next step is to create a virtual folder corresponding to physical location of the images. So that others can work on the website on their own machines, and access the images from one location.

I am new to IIS tools. How should I proceed, even in a general over-view that helps me figure it out?

It was suggested to me that this virtual folder in IIS should be a sub-directory of my working folder.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a site on IIS so that it can add virtual directory.

There is an example you can refer to it.

- I create a site named "ShareImg" and it binds to localhost:8006.
- There are two images in root folder. Enable Directory Browsing so that users can see images in the site.
  [image]
- Add a virtual Directory, Alias named share and it points to a folder(The folder doesn't under root folder). Enable its Directory Browsing,too. It can be accessed through localhost:8006/share.
  [image]
- The images urls are localhost:8006/xxxx.jpg and localhost:8006/share/xxx.jpg. Others can insert these urls in webpage or application to use images.

[image]